# How to detect `gtk_application_prefer_dark_theme` in flatpak

Tags: gtk, flatpak

When installed normally, my application detects if the system chose dark variant from checking `gtk_application_prefer_dark_theme` property from `Gtk.Settings`. But when it is packaged with Flatpak, it always detects light theme. Is it possible to detect this in Flatpak?

Answer (score 3):

Flatpak has some theming related constraints that might come into play here:

[Flatpak reference to Desktop Integration and Theming](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/desktop-integration.html?highlight=theme#theming)

For me the following solved the problem that Builder would not switch to dark mode even though it has an explicit option for it in the preferences

```
flatpak install org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Adwaita-dark
```

As flatpak uses container isolation, it turns out you need to explicitly install the dark theme via flatpak in addition to the theme you normally use in the system.

You can check with `flatpak list` if the theme you use normally as your dark theme is accessiable to flatpaks. You can also find all available themes with `flatpak search org.gtk.Gtk3theme`

Comment: i cannot get chromium flatpak to use any dark theme. i have Adwaita-dark and breeze-dark installed but still dont take. im on manjaro kde stable. id like to use breeze-dark to match the default dark plasma theme but ill take any dark if needed.